# Assign new slot clicked() for button

Tags: qt

I have copied several buttons in design form. As result all buttons got the same slot for `clicked()`. How to create and assign new personal slots for buttons?

UPD

Trying to use `Signals & Slots editor`. It was empty in the beginning, and I added new one:

[image]

But if I `right click on button btnInfoCB->go to slot.. clicked()` , it will point me to the same old method.

Comment: Just add your new button slot and connect your button to it. `connect(yourButton, &QPushButton::clicked, yourWidget, &MyWidget::SlotMyButtonClicked);`

Comment: But how to add new slot?

Comment: Do you want to add your own function slot from the designer?

Comment: I just want delete existing slot and create new one

Comment: From the designer use the [Signals & Slots editor](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/designer-connection-mode.html#editing-and-deleting-connections)

Comment: I was trying to use Signals and Slots editor. More details in question body.

Answer (score 0):

Qt creator will create slots for you. From designer, Right click on any push button and select 'Go to slots' option. select Clicked() signal press OK. Qt creator will navigate you to the created slot.  Qt automatically connects your button clicked signal to the created slots.

You can do the same for all push buttons you created

Comment: And in my case it connects to `_clicked()` function that is used by another button. I would like to correct it and assign fresh new function to button

Answer (score 0):

Qt has an auto-connect feature that connects the slots named like this: `on_UIELEMENTNAME_SIGNALNAME(SIGNAL_PARAMS)` with the corresponding signal of the ui element, see the documentation [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-a-ui-file.html#widgets-and-dialogs-with-auto-connect)

So to fix this you have 2 options:

Option 1: rename the slots to have all the names corresponding with the names from .ui file:

```
private slots:
    void on_MyFirstBtn_clicked();
    void on_MySecondBtn_clicked();
    //and so on
```

Or use option 2: manually connect

```
private slots:
    //notice the prefix "on_" and the suffix "_clicked()" not part of the function name
    void MyFirstBtnClicked();
    void MySecondBtnClicked();
```

And in the constructor of the class (i named it MyWidget) add the connect calls:

```
    connect(ui->MyFirstBtn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MyWidget::MyFirstBtnClicked);
    connect(ui->MySecondBtn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MyWidget::MySecondBtnClicked);
```

LE: I don't recommend using the UI Designer for connecting slots that are defined in code because of maintainability reasons. That feature in Designer is very good if you need to connect already defined signals and slots, like check/unched to show/hide and other similar predefined functionality, but for your defined slots i don't like it.

Answer (score 0):

**New slot for an existing QPushButton /w auto connection**

You have to change the *objectName* of `QPushButton` first. Then right click and create a new slot connection e. g. `clicked()`. Qt Creator will then create a new slot with the new `objectName` e. g. `void on_newObjectName_clicked() { }`. The old slot is no longer used then and you will get a *new fresh function*.

**Manually connect /w signals and slots editor**

If you like to connect it through your editor, you first have to click at the QWidget (e. g. MainWindow) and select change *signals/slots* from the menu. There you have to add a new function e. g. `myNewSlot()`, which is then available in the drop-down in the signals and slots editor as shown in your screenshot. If you use this type of connection you need to declare the slot in your `.h` in `private slots` and in the `.cpp` file. The object name may still link to an auto connection, so you probably need to change the objectName as well or remove the auto connected slot.